# How to create xfa pdf on Linux?

Tags: linux, pdf, forms

I know about things like Google drive for viewing pdf with xfa data on Linux, but my point is about creating such pdf1.7 files (Given adobe dropped unix support).

So what is the ghostscript(or other tool) command for creating such pdf ?

Comment: wine can run Adobe Acrobat 2015, but it’s not pratical, and Acrobat is not free.